# How to edit copyright text using data patch in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, data-patch

In admin, copyright text can be edited like this: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-update-copyright-notice-magento-2.html
But how to edit copyright via data patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copyright is retrieved by

`src/vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Footer.php`

```
/**
 * Retrieve copyright information
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCopyright()
{
    if (!$this->_copyright) {
        $this->_copyright = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'design/footer/copyright',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
    return __($this->_copyright);
}
```

So you have 2 way of doing things.

Either you define your copyright directly by extending this method with a preference

`<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" type="Company\Cms\Block\Html\Footer" />`

Either you update the matching configuration directly

You can do that using the following

```
$this->configInterface->saveConfig('design/footer/copyright', "YOUR_VALUE", 'stores',$storeId);
```